# Why does the mandelbrot set seem to end at a copy of itself?

Tags: fractals, complex-dynamics

I don't know if this is necessarily true or not, but all the mandelbrot set zooming videos seem to end in a picture of concentric circles (since the zoom is so precise, the fractals that have very small details) and a slightly different looking version of the original mandelbrot set or if not just a rotated original mandelbrot set. I'm just curious why do these videos end this way? Is it purely coincidence or is it a property of the final iterate, or does the computation become easier to zoom and stops once it reaches the converging parts of the mandelbrot set? Here is an example picture..

[image]

Comment: I really think it's just a matter of choice on the part of the person who generated the animation.

Answer (score 6):

Pretty sure it's an aesthetic choice, as Mark says in his comment.  It arguably makes a more satisfying end to end inside a mini copy (or just before).  Alternatives are to end outside the set (which would fill the screen with a flat colour eventually), or on the boundary (perhaps spiralling forever into a Misiurewicz point).

With pertubation and series approximation techniques being used for deep zooms, it can be computationally cheaper to reuse the primary reference computations between keyframes, and a central mini copy makes for a good primary reference.  But that has to be weighed up against the iteration counts increasing asymptotically more quickly when approaching a mini copy than when approaching a Misiurewicz point, for example.  The computation time for the last few keyframes of a video ending at a mini copy can dominate the time taken for the rest of the video.